# Bootstrap overlaps with my css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

my `<div>` shapes changed when I added Bootstrap to my file. This is how my design looked before I added Bootstrap:

[image]

After I added Bootstrap:

[image]

My Layout html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
     <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
       @@import "@Url.Content("~/Content/admin.css")"
    </style>
    @RenderSection("Header",false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="kapsayici">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="anasayfa-m"><a href="">Anasayfa</a></li>
                <li class="yazilar-m"><a href="">Yazılar</a></li>
                <li class="kategoriler-m"><a href="">Kategoriler</a></li>
                <li class="sayfalar-m"><a href="">Sayfalar</a></li>
                <li class="gorunum-m"><a href="">Görünüm</a></li>
                <li class="yorumlar-m"><a href="">Yorumlar</a></li>
                <li class="kullanicilar-m"><a href="">Kullanıcılar</a></li>
            </ul><br />
        </div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main HTML page:

```
<div class="yazilar"><span>Yazılar</span></div>
<div class="kategoriler"><span>Kategoriler</span></div>
<div class="sayfalar"><span>Sayfalar</span></div>
<div class="gorunum"><span>Görünüm</span></div>
<div class="yorumlar"><span>Yorumlar</span></div>
<div class="kullanicilar"><span>Kullanıcılar</span></div>
```

admin.css:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
.kapsayici {
float: left;
padding-left: 18%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.yazilar, .kategoriler, .sayfalar, .gorunum, .yorumlar, .kullanicilar {
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 32.36%;
}
.wrapper ~ div {
font-family: Verdana;
}
div span {
float: left;
margin: 50% 35%;
}
.kategoriler, .sayfalar {
margin-left: 1%; 
}
.gorunum {
margin-top: 1%;
clear: left;
}
.yorumlar, .kullanicilar {
margin-left: 1%;
margin-top: 1%; 
}
.yazilar {
background:url(../Images/icons/yazılar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.kategoriler {
background:url(../Images/icons/kategori.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.sayfalar {
background:url(../Images/icons/sayfalar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.gorunum {
background:url(../Images/icons/theme.png) #e1e1e1  no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.yorumlar {
background:url(../Images/icons/comments.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.kullanicilar {
background:url(../Images/icons/users.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.yazilar:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/yazılar.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.kategoriler:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/kategori.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.sayfalar:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/sayfalar.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.gorunum:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/theme.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.yorumlar:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/comments.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
.kullanicilar:hover {
background:url(../Images/icons/users.png) #eeeeee no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 30%;
}
/* menü */
ul.menu { 
    width: 62%;
    height: 11%;
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    background-color: #e1e1e1;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #e1e1e1;
}
ul.menu li { 
    float: left;
    width: 13.14%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.menu li a {
position: relative;
top: 70%;
left: 27%;
color: #000;
}
ul.menu li:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid #FFF;
}
ul.menu li.kategoriler-m a {
left: 23%;
}
ul.menu li.sayfalar-m a {
left: 31%;
}
ul.menu li.yazilar-m a {
left: 35%;
}
ul.menu li.yazilar-m {
background: url(../Images/icons/myazılar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.kategoriler-m {
background: url(../Images/icons/mkategori.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.sayfalar-m {
background: url(../Images/icons/msayfalar.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.gorunum-m {
background: url(../Images/icons/mtheme.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.yorumlar-m {
background: url(../Images/../Images/icons/mcomments.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li.kullanicilar-m {
border-right: none;
background: url(../Images/icons/musers.png) #e1e1e1 no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 35%;
}
ul.menu li a { 
        text-decoration: none; 
}
```

I tried to find out which `<div>` overlaps can cause this problem but I didn't find anything. Thanks for your help in advance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MDGZ7/

Comment: Can you make a demo in jsfiddle

Comment: @ndcweb sorry I can't because I cant add Bootstrap in jsfiddle. If there is a way for adding both bootstrap and my css , I can make a demo.

Comment: There is a way to add Bootstrap to jsfiddle. Click on External resources on the left, and add paths to bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js from some CDN. Unfortunately I have to go out now, but I'll check it later, if no one else helped you.

Comment: @ndcweb oh, I've just learned it after you said, thanks. I added fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is normalize.css that Bootstrap contains. Reason of this situation is that the page isn't designed with Bootstrap and Bootstrap was added after the design process of the page. The solutions are:

1- Redesign the page with Bootstrap

2- Deactivate part of the bootstrap.css that contains normalize.css (But it's not permanent solution in my opinion.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest playing around in Chrome's developer tools. Bootstrap uses Normalize.css which resets some CSS elements to their default values (or something like that). Use the developer tools to find which styles were reset (you can check the styles on and off to see how it affects the page).

Comment: Or use firebug in firefox... even more robust toolset